# Асинхронный json на c#

Tags: c#, json, асинхронность

Мне надо обработать 20 элементов, полученных с помощью json. Элементы могут быть двух типов, и для каждого надо запросить разную дополнительную информацию.
Я использую асинхронные методы для получения информации в json ответе, но проблема в том, что получается обработать только 8 элементов из 20. Если добавить задержку Thread.Sleep() то он все правильно обрабатывает.

Это мой первый опыт в асинхронном программировании, так что сам разобраться никак не могу. Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Вот общий метод для json ответов:

```
async public static Task<T> request(string method, string fields)
{
    //Запрос
    string main = "https://url";

    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(
      main + method + fields);

    WebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync();
    Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

    T req = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseFromServer);

    return req;
}
```

А вот уже основная функция:

```
async public Task GetElem()
{
    //Получаем 20 элементов
    GetItems = await json_request<GetTypes>.request("GetTypes", "count=20");
    int a = 0;
    while (a < 20)
    {
        //Создаем новую промежуточную структуру
        Test_mas mas1 = new Test_mas();
        //Общее поле для элементов обоих типов
        mas1.item1 = GetItems.items[a].field1;
        //Проверяем тип элемента
        if (GetItems.items[a].type == "type_1")
        {
            //Получаем дополнительную информацию, отдельная функция
            var type1 = await GetType_1(a);
            //Присваиваем полученную информацию 
            mas1.item2 = type1.fields1;
            mas1.item3 = type1.fields2;

        }
        else if (GetItems.items[a].type == "type_2")
        {
            //Получаем дополнительную информацию, отдельная функция
            var type2 = await GetType_2(a);
            //Присваиваем полученную информацию 
            mas1.item2 = type2.fields1;
            mas1.item3 = type2.fields2;

        }
        //Добавляем в общий список
        mass.Add(mas1);
        a++;
    }
}
```

И вот наконец метод для получения дополнительной информации:

```
async public Task<type1> GetType_1(int a)
{
    string method = "type1";
    string fields = "field";
    int id = GetItems.items[a].id;
    //Выполняем функцию для json ответа
    var user = json_request<type1>.request(method, fields + "id=" + id);
    return await user;
}
```

Функция для обработки элемента 2 типа почти ничем не отличается.

Пример json:
Для GetTypes:

```
{
    "count": 20,
    "items": [{
        "id": 1,
        "type": "type_1",
        "field1" : "string"
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "type": "type_2",
        "field1" : "string" 
    }]
}
```

А вот для type1 и 2

```
{
    "id":  1,
    "fields1": "string",
    "fields2": "string"
}
```

Comment: кони, люди, мухи, котлеты - все в одном месте, нужно не добавлять паузы в потоки, а указать ожидание до полной загрузки документа. ответов миллион  на этом ресурсе.

Comment: @AK Простите, исправил

Comment: А где вы добавляете Thread.Sleep?

Comment: @VadimBondaruk Я не стал писать в коде, так как это даже не костыль. Но так я добавляю в цикл while.

Comment: Это консольное приложение? Как вы вызываете метод GetElem? Что такое объект mass и где он создается?

Comment: А еще лучше выложите проект на github

Comment: @VadimBondaruk Прошу прощения за задержку в ответе. Uwp с ui, вызывается из конструктора без await, а mass это  public static ObservableCollection<Test_mas>, а Test_mas это просто public static с 3 полями типа string, создаются в общем классе. Да там и выкладывать то, что связано с этой проблемой, больше нечего в сущности то.